# Directory API users.list returns 403 with service account

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client, google-directory-api

I'm trying to use a Service Account to programmatically create users with the Admin Directory API.

The service account has been granted domain-wide delegation and has been authorized by an admin with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` scope.

As proof of concept, I tried to simply list all users on our domain with this code:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const KEY = require('./mykey.json');

function connect() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      KEY.client_email,
      null,
      KEY.private_key,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'],
      null
    );

    jwtClient.authorize((err) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(jwtClient);
      }
    });
  });
}

function listUsers(client) {
  return new Promise((yep, nope) => {
    google.admin('directory_v1').users.list({
      auth: client,
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
    }, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        return nope(err);
      }
      return yep(response);
    });
  });
}
```

This is done in the context of a Firebase Cloud Function called like this:

```
function getAllUsers() {
  return connect().then((client) => (listUsers(client)));
}

exports.getAllUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  getAllUsers().then((users) => {
    res.status(200).send(users);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(`Something went wrong :: ${err}`);
  });
});
```

When I authenticate the request without impersonating a user, I get an error that says `Not Authorized to access this resource/api`. And when I authenticate the request while imitating an admin user (the second `null` in the `connect()` method above), I get an error that says `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.`

I've followed all documentation to a T, and every related answer I've found seems to point to "domain-wide delegation" not being enabled, which it definitely is.

Grateful for any assistance...

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Comment: nothing yet. i've opened an issue on github asking for more clarification on using service accounts in this context. feel free to upvote for visibility - https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/912